# Group switch-statement in R

Tags: r, switch-statement

I have a variable `i` that maps to a set of categories.

I wish to set the variable `sector` to the matching category, based on the value of `i`.

I am able to do this with a series of `if` statements, as follows:

```
    if(i %in% c(7, 14, 21)) {sector = 'mining'} 
    if(i %in% c(28, 35, 42)) {sector = 'manu'} 
    if(i %in% c(49, 56, 63)) {sector = 'othr'} 
    if(i %in% c(70, 77, 84)) {sector = 'all'}
```

This seems like the sort of thing for which there ought to be a grouped switch type structure available.  Is there such a thing in R?

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
L <- list(mining = c(7, 14, 12), 
      manu = c(28, 35, 42), 
      other = c(49, 56, 63), 
      all = c(70, 77, 84))
names(Filter(function(x) i %in% x, L))
```

UPDATE: Regarding Ben's comment, here is a short circuiting version.  (If the motivation for this comment was speed then note that `?Position` says: "The current implementation is not optimized for performance.")

```
names(L)[ Position(function(x) i %in% x, L) ]
```

Comment: it would be nice to figure out a way to make this short-circuit [stop after the first match was found] ...

Answer (score 3):

Typically you would use a lookup table.

```
lookup <- data.frame(id = c(7,14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84),
                     sector=rep(c("mining","manu","othr","all"),each=3),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#use the lookup data.frame
lookup[lookup$id == 49,"sector"]
#[1] "othr"

merge(data.frame(i=c(14,21,56,84,7)),lookup,by.x="i",by.y="id")
#    i sector
# 1  7 mining
# 2 14 mining
# 3 21 mining
# 4 56   othr
# 5 84    all
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `switch()` statement.  Note that for non-consecutive values, you must uses characters:

```
getSector <- function(code) {
    sector <- switch(as.character(code),
                     "7" = "mining",
                     "14" = "mining",
                     "21" = "mining",
                     "28" = "manu",
                     "35" = "manu",
                     "42" = "manu",
                     "49" = "othr",
                     "56" = "othr",
                     "63" = "othr",
                     "70" = "all",
                     "77" = "all",
                     "84" = "all")
}
```

Of course, looking a little more closely at your codes, you can translate them to consecutive integers leading to this:

```
getSector2 <- function(code) {
    sector <- switch(ceiling(code/7/3),
                     "mining",
                     "manu",
                     "othr",
                     "all")
}
```

We can reduce this further to

```
getSectors3 <- function(code) {
    sectors <- c("mining", "manu", "othr", "all")
    sectors[ ceiling(code/7/3) ]
}
```